# I can't understand "Functions in Simplified JavaScript are lambdas with lexical scoping."

Tags: javascript, function, lambda

I'm reading Douglas Crockford's book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". I can't understand the sentence that "Functions in Simplified JavaScript are lambdas with lexical scoping.". What does this sentence want to tell us? How do you understand this sentence?

Thank you very much!

Below is the contexts of this sentence in the book:

> I wanted to include all of the code
>   for a parser in JavaScript that parses
>   JavaScript. But my chapter was just
>   one of 30 or 40, so I felt constrained
>   in the number of pages I could
>   consume. A further complication was
>   that most of my readers would have no
>   experience with JavaScript, so I also
>   would have to introduce the language
>   and its peculiarities.
>
> So, I decided to subset the language.
>   That way, I wouldn't have to parse the
>   whole language, and I wouldn't have to
>   describe the whole language. I called
>   the subset Simplified JavaScript.
>   Selecting the subset was easy: it
>   included just the features that I
>   needed to write a parser. This is how
>   I described it in Beautiful Code:
>
> Simplified JavaScript is just the good
>   stuff, including:
>
> **Functions as firortranst class objects**
>
> **Functions in Simplified JavaScript are lambdas with lexical scoping.**
>
> Dynamic objects with prototypal
>   inheritance
>
> Objects are class-free. We can add a
>   new member to any object by ordinary
>   assignment. An object can inherit
>   members from another object.
>
> Object literals and array literals
>
> This is a very convenient notation for
>   creating new objects and arrays.
>   JavaScript literals were the
>   inspiration for the JSON data
>   interchange format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's attempting to explain the nature of function declarations in JavaScript.  By describing them as "lambdas with lexical scoping" he's eluding to the number of ways they can be used.  You can, for example, declare them statically:

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  // do something
}
```

You can store them in a variable:

```
var myFunc = function(arg) {
  // do something
};
```

You can use them as object properties (methods):

```
var myObject = {
  myMethod: function (arg) {
    // do something
  }
};
```

Or you can declare them as you pass them somewhere (very common when working with jQuery):

```
$('.myClass').click(function () {
  // do something when an element with class "myClass" is clicked.
});
```

Because of the flexibility in when / how they're declared they fill the same role that lambdas do in many other languages (Python for example).

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function is another term for an anonymous function. He is saying that javascript supports anonymous functions ( you can create functions on the fly without giving them names, such as var myVar = function () { ... } ). Lexical scoping is referring to how javascript handles scope. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_versus_dynamic_scoping